# Bucle for anidado en listas para evaluar 2 valores de un elemento

Tags: javascript

De entrada una lista ejemplo [[18, 20],[45, 2],[61, 12],[37, 6],[21, 21],[78, 9]]
con ella debo categorizar la membresia si tiene màs o igual de 55 en la posiciòn 0 y màs de 7 en posiciòn 1 de la lista es "Senior" menor a esos valores "Open" lo mismo con las siguientes posiciones de la lista
hice este codigo:

```
function openOrSenior(data){
let membresias = [];
 for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   for(let h = 1; h < data.length; h++){   
    if(data[i][i] >= 55 && data[i][h] > 7){
      membresias.push("Senior");
    }else{
      membresias.push("Open");
    }
   }
 }
  return membresias;
}
```

que me da de retorno la lista membresias pero solo el valor que esta en el else de la condicional osea "Open"
Que falla?

Comment: Primero: `if(data[i][i] >= 55` no debería ser `if(data[i][h] >= 55`? Y segundo, el segundo bucle debería ser: `for(let h = 1; h < data[i].length; h++)` puesto que cada lista solo tiene dos valores, y así estarías intentando recorrer 6.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor haz el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Debes [edit] tu pregunta porque tiene fallas de redacción y, esas fallas se reflejan en tu código, y hacen que no puedas obtener lo que buscas. Si corriges la redacción te darás cuenta de que necesitas sólo un bucle y verificar que data[i][0] > 54 y luego (con y sin else ) que data[i][1]>7. Pero, como la pregunta está mal formulada es posible que las respuestas que demos no te ayuden, pues debemos suponer detalles que no están claros en la formulación.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener la entrada sin hacer uso de 2 bucles for, por ejemplo este código deberia funcionar

```
function openOrSenior(data){
var membresia = [];
  for (var i of data){
    if (i[0] > 54 && i[1] > 7) membresia.push("Senior");
    else membresia.push("Open");
  }
  return membresia;
}
```